# Почему может не работает z индекс на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

Не работает z индекс в чем может быть дело

```css
.header__content {
    padding-top: 98px;
    background: var(--primery-color);
}
.header__content__wrap {
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 130px;

    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
}
.title {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 48px;
    line-height: 54px;
    color: var(--primery-color);
}
.title__header {
    color: var(--white-color);
    line-height: 65px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.text {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 27px;
    color: var(--primery-color);
}
.text__header {
    margin-top: 18px;
    color: var(--white-color);
    max-width: 475px;
    z-index: 10;
}
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__content">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="header__content__wrap">
          <h1 class="title title__header">Running the show <br> has never been so <br> easy.</h1>
          <p class="text text__header">Ready to put the human back in HR? Clerksy helps you set the stage with an inclusive and compliant workplace.</p>
          <img class="hero" src="img/hero.png" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Что значит не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Предположу, что вы хотите, чтобы текст из `h1` и `p` был поверх изображения. Поэтому у изображения стоит `z-index: 0` а у текста `z-index: 10`

> CSS-свойство z-index определяет положение **позиционированного элемента** и его дочерних ....

Подробнее тут [ссылка](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Пример:

```css
:root {
  --primery-color: blue;
  --white-color: #fff;
}

.header__content {
  padding-top: 98px;
  background: var(--primery-color);
}

.header__content__wrap {
  padding-top: 120px;
  padding-bottom: 130px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.title {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 48px;
  line-height: 54px;
  color: var(--primery-color);
}

.title__header {
  color: var(--white-color);
  line-height: 65px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.text {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 27px;
  color: var(--primery-color);
}

.text__header {
  margin-top: 18px;
  color: var(--white-color);
  max-width: 475px;
  z-index: 10;
  position: relative;
}

.hero {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="header__content">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header__content__wrap">
      <h1 class="title title__header">Running the show <br> has never been so <br> easy.</h1>
      <p class="text text__header">Ready to put the human back in HR? Clerksy helps you set the stage with an inclusive and compliant workplace.</p>
      <img class="hero" src="https://thypix.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/tree-clipart-transparent-8-700x613.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```